# How does one sort dates in a text file?

Tags: command-line, date, sort

It's 14.08.2019, there is a text file that contains a list of dates (dd.mm.yyyy):

```
30.07.2018
14.08.2019
18.08.2019
20.08.2019
01.01.2020
```

The dates in the list are deadlines.

What the output should look like: a list of dates that are older than the current date and dates that are going to expire in 10 days (if it expires in 1 to 10 days it's listed and if it expires today it's also listed. If it expires in 11 or more days then it's not listed).

Comment: The output format does not involve sorting in any form or shape as far as I can see at the moment, and whatever algorithm I can think of would not requirer sorting of the input data either. Why do you need sorting?

Comment: Since you can sort dates in a file from oldest to newest and vise versa then there should be a way to "filter" things out. I'm actually wondering if that can be done in the command line.

Comment: Could you give an example of the output?

Comment: If you can install an additional package, `dateutils` will make your life easier: http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/

Comment: You could do this as a one-liner by first sending the output through `date` to get the date as seconds from 1970.  Pipe that to a comparison, and if more than 10 days in the future, just drop that line.  You could put a `sort` in here if you want, and finally, use `date` to convert back.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `date`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
printf '%s days\n' -1 +10 |
  date -f - +%d.%m.%YT |
  sort -nt. -k3 -k2 -k1 -- - "$@" |
  sed '/T/,/T/!d;/T/d'
```

The idea being to sort the list where we've inserted a date for yesterday and 10 days later ending in `T`, so for instance if run on 2019-08-14, we get:

```
30.07.2018
13.08.2019T
14.08.2019
18.08.2019
20.08.2019
24.08.2019T
01.01.2020
```

And we extract the part between those two `T` lines.

```
$ faketime 2019-08-14 that-script your-file
14.08.2019
18.08.2019
20.08.2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`, or `mawk`:

```
$ cat file
30.07.2018
13.08.2019
14.08.2019
18.08.2019
20.08.2019
21.08.2019
23.08.2019
24.08.2019
25.08.2019
01.01.2020
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk file   # running this on 2019-08-14
30.07.2018      expired 380 days ago
13.08.2019      expired 1 days ago
14.08.2019      expires in 0 days
18.08.2019      expires in 4 days
20.08.2019      expires in 6 days
21.08.2019      expires in 7 days
23.08.2019      expires in 9 days
24.08.2019      expires in 10 days
```

This will output the dates in the same order as the input data, with each date suffixed by a tab and a short message.  Dates eleven days in the future or more will not be outputted.

The `awk` script:

```awk
BEGIN {
        FS = "."
        now = systime()/(24*60*60) - 1
}

{
        datespec = sprintf("%s %s %s 00 00 00", $3, $2, $1)
        timestamp = mktime(datespec)/(24*60*60)

        diff = timestamp - now

        if (diff < 0)
                message = sprintf("expired %d days ago", 1 - diff)
        else if (diff < 11)
                message = sprintf("expires in %d days", diff)
        else
                next

        printf("%s\t%s\n", $0, message)
}
```

`mawk` and GNU `awk` has been extended with date/time-related functions, and here we are using `systime()` to get the current time as a UNIX timestamp (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00).  We round this to full days by dividing by the number of seconds in a day.

For each input line, we use the three dot-delimited numbers with `mktime()` to create a UNIX timestamp for midnight on the given date (the very start of the day) and round this to full days as with `now` and call it `timestamp`.

Then it's a matter of comparing `now` and `timestamp` and figuring out what to print depending on how they differ.

See the documentation for GNU `awk` or `mawk` for how they document `systime()` and `mktime()`.

---

Sorting the dates by computing their corresponding UNIX timestamps, prefixing the dates by this, sorting numerically, and discarding the now used timestamps (using `mawk` or GNU `awk`):

```
$ awk -F . -v OFS="\t" '{ print mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d 00 00 00", $3, $2, $1)), $0 }' file | sort -n | cut -f 2
30.07.2018
13.08.2019
14.08.2019
18.08.2019
20.08.2019
21.08.2019
23.08.2019
24.08.2019
25.08.2019
01.01.2020
```

The same thing, but simpler, and also works with BSD `awk`:

```
$ awk -F . -v OFS="\t" '{ print sprintf("%s-%s-%s", $3, $2, $1), $0 }' file | sort | cut -f 2
30.07.2018
13.08.2019
14.08.2019
18.08.2019
20.08.2019
21.08.2019
23.08.2019
24.08.2019
25.08.2019
01.01.2020
```

This works by simply converting the dates into the YYYY-MM-DD ([ISO 8601 Calendar date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates)) format and sorting lexicographically on that rather than the UNIX timestamps.

Using the YYYY-MM-DD date format from the start would have made sorting much simpler, but we would still have to do the same sort of calculations as in the first `awk` script above to be able to (easily) say "this day is more than 10 days into the future".

Answer (score 0):

I have come to this, if I understood you well, and taking the answer of @Kunasalanda as example:

> This is using bash (or compatible shell) and GNU date. It would fall over on e.g. macOS (non-GNU date).

```
today=$(date -d $(date +'%Y-%m-%d') +%s)

while read i; do
  [[ -z "$i" ]] && continue
  date_format=$(echo "$i" | awk -F'.' -vOFS='-' '{print $3,$2,$1}')
  convert_date=$(date -d "$date_format" +%s)
  if [[ "$convert_date" -ge "$today" ]]; then
    expires=$(( ("$convert_date"- "$today")/86400 ))
    [[ ! "$expires" -gt 10 ]] && echo $i expires in $expires days
  fi
done < file
```

Ouput:

```
14.08.2019 expires in 0 days
18.08.2019 expires in 4 days
20.08.2019 expires in 6 days
```

---

Ignore blank lines

```
[[ -z "$i" ]] && continue
```

---

Format `dd.mm.yy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` to be able to perform operations

```
date_format=$(echo "$i" | awk -F'.' -vOFS='-' '{print $3,$2,$1}')
```

---

Convert date to seconds

```
convert_date=$(date -d "$date_format" +%s)
```

---

Choose only dates greater than today

```
if [[ "$convert_date" -ge "$today" ]]; then
```

---

Get the days that the given date will expire

```
expires=$(( ("$convert_date"- "$today")/86400 ))
```

---

Output only if expiration is not greater than 10 days

```
[[ ! "$expires" -gt 10 ]] && echo "$i" expires in "$expires" days
```

Comment: You should mention that this is using `bash` (or compatible shell) and GNU `date`. It would fall over on e.g. macOS (non-GNU `date`).